# Robust statistics linear regression in seaborn pairplot

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, seaborn

Trying to implement robust statistics instead of ordinary least squares (OLS) fitting so that outliers aren't such a problem to my fits. 
I was hoping to implement this in the pairplot function of seaborn and can't see and easy way to add this from the AP documentation as there doesn't seem to be a key word argument for the fit.

From: [scipy lectures](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/packages/statistics/index.html) They suggest using the following but I guess thats for regplot where you can define the fit using

```
`fit = statsmodels.formula.api.rlm()`
```

Here is some sample code

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(iris, kind="reg")#, robust = True)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found a workaround, but loose the 'hue' function apparently that could be done on the pairplot. Would be a nice feature to add robust option to pairplot. 
Code:

```
def corrfunc(x, y, **kws): 
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y) 
    ax = plt.gca() 
    ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r), xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes) 

g = sns.PairGrid(df1, palette=["red"]) 
g.map_upper(sns.regplot, robust = True) 
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=True) 
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d") 
g.map_lower(corrfunc)
```

Comment: I found a workaround, but loose the 'hue' function apparently that could be done on the pairplot. Would be a nice feature to add robust option to pairplot.
Code:
`    def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
        r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r),
                    xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

    g = sns.PairGrid(df1, palette=["red"])
    g.map_upper(sns.regplot, robust = True)
    g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=True)
    g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
    g.map_lower(corrfunc)    `

Comment: In your workaround, you can include the hue with g = sns.PairGrid(df1, hue='species')

Answer (score 0):

Extra keywords, such as "robust = True" can be passed to regplot via the plot_kws argument:

```
sns.pairplot(df1,kind='reg',hue='species',plot_kws=dict(robust=True,n_boot=50))
```

NB: In this example I have also decreased n_boot to reduce the runtime (see "robust" in regplot documentation), so the confidence intervals might be incorrect).